# NET Core 3.1 - How can I exclude parameters from being lowercased in urls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

In my web application I want the urls to be lowercased, but the parameters should preserve their case, since they are case-sensitive. I use this in my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

And in the `Configure` method in `app.UseEndpoints` I have this:

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "area",
    areaName: "App",
    pattern: "app/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

The problem is that the id of the entity can't be lowercase and when I create a route like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", new {id = group.Id})">Some link</a>
```

The id will be lowercased, thus the generated link would be wrong. Does anyone have an idea of an easy way to exclude the id from being lowercased?

Comment: Did you try setting `options.LowercaseQueryStrings = false`?

Comment: @Marlon I tried you suggestions, but still does not work. To explain I want the id inside the path to preserve the case `http://my-app.com/groups/wbCJYCClcxpezjmFAnuLzimgsP/posts`, instead the id is being lower cased `/wbcjycclcxpezjmfanulzimgsp`. Anyways since I am just starting my project I decided to switch to [IdGen](https://github.com/RobThree/IdGen) which generates random integer IDs, which would not have this problem.